# How do I use the proper linux header extension folder

Tags: linux, gcc, make

I am trying to build a TP-Link driver and when I run `make` I get...

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=armv7l CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.19.118-v7+/build M=/home/.../Download/Driver  modules
```

I can tell this is wrong it should be `4.19.118-v7l+` where there is a build directory.

There is a `4.19.118-v7+` but no build directory. What am I missing?